# Shortcut to open a specific file in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'd like to define a keyboard shortcut to open a specific file (in this case my todo file).

I don't know if there is a command I can use in the keyboard settings.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Even if there might not exist a direct command to do that, it is likely that you will be able to create a "macro" to open the file, and then bind it to a shortcut. Please show us what you have tried. Do not hesitate to answer your own question.

Answer (score 6):

The solution that relies on launching the `code` command in Tasks feels a bit heavyweight and does not work with Code-Server. Here's a more "native" approach:

1. Install the [VSCode Macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EXCEEDSYSTEM.vscode-macros) extension.
2. Make a file `macros.js` somewhere (e.g. in `$workspace/.vscode/macros.js`):

   ```js
   const vscode = require('vscode');

   module.exports.macroCommands = {
      OpenTodo: {
         no: 1,
         func: () => openFile("/full/path/to/your/todo.md")
      },
   };

   async function openFile(filename) {
     const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(filename);
     const editor = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
   }
   ```
3. Add to your `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "vscodemacros.userMacroCommands": [
     {
       "path": "/full/path/to/your/.vscode/macros.js",
       "name": "OpenTodo"
     },
   ]
   ```
4. Open Keyboard Shortcuts (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S by default), find the command "VCSMacros: User Macro1" and map it to a key of your preference. Reload window (at least in code-server that was necessary for the keyboard shortcut to start working).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this quick and powerful feature combination! Quite useful to catch the edge cases VSCode can't handle. Much apprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with tasks, here is how:

Open your `tasks.json` file:

```
F1 -> type: "Tasks: Configure Tasks" -> select: "Open tasks.json file"
```

Paste in the following:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "openMyFile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "path_to_your_VSCode path_to_your_file.txt"
        },
    ]
}
```

In your `keybindings.json` add:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+scrolllock", # Or some other binding
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "openMyFile" # <- Your task's name in this case openMyFile
},
```

That should do it.

Comment: It works exactly as you described: I has to create the tasks.json file first since it didn't exist, and add 'code' app to the PATH using command palette. It is quite slow, but it works. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear! You can mark my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70800478/3018229) and was pointed towards the [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) extension, which provides a command for exactly this purpose. You can add a keybinding for it like this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+i n",  // or any other combo
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "C:\\Projects\\Notes\\notes.txt",
      "method": "vscode.open",
    }
}
```

If you are (like me) usually working on remote machines using the remote SSH extension but want to open a local file on your computer, add the `"useScheme": "vscode-local"` arument to `args`.