# vscode keyboard shortcuts to specific files

Tags: visual-studio-code, macros, key-bindings

In vscode I want direct keyboard shortcuts assigned to specific files, the most used, in the active project, something like

> Alt+1 -> sourcefile1.ts
>
> Alt+2 -> settings.json
>
> etc...

(each shortcut would open/bring to focus that file in the editor)

So far I haven't found a solution, I have to dig further but I wonder if there's already an obvious solution for this, perhaps some plugin otherwise what would be the the simplest approach?

Comment: [Quick Open](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_quick-open) allows you to open a file by name, and puts recently opened files at the top of the list by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes but I want something even more quick and invariable, when I press alt +3 I will get  xxxx.yyy no matter if it's already open or not

Comment: Duplicate of [Shortcut to open a specific file in VSC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711834/shortcut-to-open-a-specific-file-in-vsc).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with keybindings like this:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "code -r 'test.js'\u000d" }
  },

  {
    "key": "alt+2",   // open workspace settings
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "code -r '.vscode/settings.json'\u000d" }
  },
```

You can use the variables listed in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference, like `${workspaceFolder}` or `${execPath}`.