# Visual Studio Code: shortcut to open a certain file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have a text file on my local drive in which I like to take random notes. I want to be able to quickly open this file in VS Code from every project I work on. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut only shows files which had already been opened before in the current workspace, so the first time I open the file in a new workspace I still have to open it manually.

Does anybody know an extension or any built-in functionality providing a quick way to open a certain file that has not been opened before? My ideal solution would be a dedicated hotkey that just opens a configurable file.

I've searched the marketplace and tried several "favorites" extensions. None of them provides what I'm looking for.

The pitfall is that the solution has to work for local files in remote workspaces as well, i.e. I am connected to a *remote* server via VS Code's remote SSH extension and still want to open the file from my *local* filesystem.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to view a local file in the remote connected VSC, that will not work, the remote VSC is a view of the remote executing VSC server

Comment: @rioV8: Well, but I am able to actually open local files using `Ctrl + O` and selecting "Show local". Or I can drag & drop a local file to my remote session VS code window. So there are actual ways to do this, I'm just looking for a shortcut for it.

Comment: That is new too me. the documented API calls to open a file do not have a (documented) option to specify `Show Local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) v0.15.1 and the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile` to open a local file. Specify the full path.

At first I did not had this extension installed in the remote computer. VSC complained that the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile` did not exist. That means that the VSC remote window uses the local key binding file but executes the commands on the remote machine. This means you have different key bindings if you are at the physical keyboard of the remote machine compared to a remote connection. The same goes if you have set your XDISPLAY (??) environment variable (for Linux systems, remote display)

You tried it with v0.14 (see comment) and found out that VSC uses the scheme `vscode-remote` (not documented).

I modified the extension so we can set the scheme of the URI.

Using scheme `file` did not work. In local VSC all local file URIs have this scheme.

But if we use the scheme `vscode-local` (that you have found somewhere) I was able to open a file from the local disk in the remote VSC instance with a key-binding.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i n",  // or any other combo
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "C:\\Projects\\Notes\\notes.txt",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split",
      "useScheme": "vscode-local"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for local files in a remote environment, because VS code makes a remote path out of it. Error message: `Unable to open 'D:\notes.txt': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+srv73/d:\notes.txt' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+srv73/d:\notes.txt').`

Comment: @carlfriedrich I can try to force it to use a different scheme `file:`

Comment: Oh, is that your extension? I found out that local file paths can be referenced using the URI scheme `vscode-local:///D:/notes.txt`. However, this only works in combination with `Uri.parse()`, which most extensions don't seem to use.

Comment: @carlfriedrich See the modified answer (`vscode-local` did the trick)

Comment: Perfect, that indeed works just like I wanted to! Thanks for the help and your good work!

Comment: The above json data should be put in `keybindings.json`